# Do Einstein Opportunity Insights and Activity Capture use Call Data?

Tags: einstein

Does Einstein Opportunity Insights use standard activities such as Call Log or Email in standard Task objects?

The Einstein Opportunity Insights Data Sheet says the following which indicates it uses engagement. It specifically mentions email and calendar, which are two items that happen to be captured by Einstein Activity Capture, but these don't seem to be captured as standard objects.

> Einstein Opportunity Insights uses your Sales Cloud data from historical sales cycles and engagement with customers (e.g., email) to discover unique patterns about your sales cycles
>
> Sales Cloud Einstein analyzes all the standard fields attached to the Opportunity data in addition to email and calendar data, and then uses machine learning, natural language processing, and statistical analysis to provide sales reps and managers with Predictions, Key Moments, and Smart Follow-Ups.

Ref: https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/datasheets/sales-cloud-einstein-opportunity-account-insights.pdf

At the same time, the email captured by Einstein Activity Capture does not appear in Salesforce as a standard object, e.g. task with type set to Email:

> we just discovered that with Einstein Activity Capture it seems that it's not creating EmailMessage objects nor Tasks, as for emails sent via salesforce mail server. This is becoming a show stopper for us and for many other SF users as well (https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005MgjQAE) as it would be the basic for some automation. For example, when a new incoming email arrives, do this (e.g. set a timer and if answer not given within 24 hours, create a warning).
>
> Is there any plan to make email messages added by EinsteinActivity capture queriable via SOQL? How about having them exactly as enhanced emails, i.e. with an EmailMessage object and a Task + EmailStatus that tracks opening?

Ref: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003UpeQAE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Einstein Activity Capture - 2017

Einstein Activity Capture uses a different database so it appears standard objects may not be covered.

> After several calls with Salesforce's support, we were told it's just not possible to have Einstein Activity Capture log the emails as Task or EmailMessage objects, and that all emails go to a different database once Einstein Activity Capture is enabled.

Ref: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005MgjQAE

## Einstein Call Coaching - Update 2020

As of 2020, Salesforce High Velocity Sales (HVS) has a feature called Einstein Call Coaching that does take call recordings.

> Einstein Call Coaching is a new feature available for sales managers that offers the ability to see insights and trends surfaced from sales calls. Calls are recorded and analyzed for mentions of specific keywords and phrases. From voice call records, managers can play call recordings and see call details, including the talk-to-listen ratio.

Read more here:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=call_coaching.htm&type=5